# Why is my WHERE clause not working as intended?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019-express

I am running a query to apply a number depending on the `WHERE` clause which verifies information from different tables

```
UPDATE EstadoDoc  
SET PuntajePrevio = 10
FROM Investigador i, Autores a, Documentos d, EstadoDoc e, Periodo p
WHERE i.IdInv = a.IdInv 
  AND a.IdDoc = d.IdDoc  
  AND d.Tipo = 'AR'   
  AND e.Estado IN ('A', 'RyR')
  AND p.FechaDesde <= e.FechaEst 
  AND p.FechaHasta >= e.FechaEst 
  AND p.IdPeriodo = 2019
```

This is the query I'm running and it's supposed to put the value 10 in `PuntajePrevio` depending on the `WHERE` clause, but I'm noticing it's not working correctly because it is applying the value to 2 column were it shouldn't.

To further explain here is a screenshot of the data it affected - it should be only taking into consideration all the ones that have `d.tipo = 'AR'` but is it not.

[image: As you can see it affected the rows with IdDoc =012, 000 and 005 in the table EstadoDoc]

[image: But as you can see in the table Documentos the rows with IdDoc=012 and 000 have tipo = AC and not AR, im wondering why is it still taking them in consideration even when the clause specifies tipo='AR']

Comment: Consumable sample data, as DDL and DML statements, not images, will help us help you here.

Comment: Also, please use modern `JOIN` syntax, this is old and confusing.

Comment: what is Consumable sample data, as DDL and DML statements?

Comment: If you switch to using `JOIN` rather than using commas in your `FROM` clause, you'd probably notice that there's **nothing** correlating your `i`, `a` and `d` tables with the `e` and `p` tables. That's probably a mistake.

Comment: [What are DDL and DML statements?](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=What+are+DDL+and+DML+statements%3F) As someone writing SQL, you should know what both of these are.

Comment: Given you're updating `e`, and the lack of correlation from any of `i`, `a` or `d`, it should come as no surprise that a condition on `d` doesn't change which `e` rows are affected.

Comment: Can you run your select query using your "where" clause. Check whether your are getting expected records for update or not.